# opencv python face detection from url images

Tags: python, url, opencv

I have no problem getting the opencv face detection using haar feature based cascades working on saved images:

```
from PIL import Image
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

img = cv2.imread('pic.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
```

but I can't figure out how to open a url image and pass it into face_cascade. I've been playing around with cStringIO, but I don't know what to do with it...

```
import cv2.cv as cv
import urllib, cStringIO
img = 'http://scontent-b.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-prn/t51.2885-15/10424498_582114441904402_1105042543_n.png'
file = cStringIO.StringIO(urllib.urlopen(img).read())
source = Image.open(file).convert("RGB")
bitmap = cv.CreateImageHeader(source.size, cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3)
cv.SetData(bitmap, source.tostring())
cv.CvtColor(bitmap, bitmap, cv.CV_RGB2BGR)
```

is it possible to work with a numpy array instead?

```
source2 = Image.open(file)
imarr=numpy.array(source2,dtype=numpy.uint8)
```

I'm a beginner, so I apologize for the poor explanation.
thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: sorry, yes, I am getting an error.
If I try to apply the COLOR_BGR2GRAY like above in gray = ...
I get the error: 
TypeError: src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

Comment: numpy array was the way to go. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example you are using `OpenCV2.imread` to read your image in the second you are presumably using `PIL.Image` then trying to convert.

Why not simply save the file to a temp directory and then use `OpenCV2.imread` again?

Comment: that would definitely work, but I'm using the python-instagram api to grab a lot of pics and I want to segment out the faces and do some visualization with that, so I was hoping to just read from the url

Comment: Assuming you have a multi-core processor if you save and then process one, using threads or multiprocessing to start the next download, and delete the file at the end of processing you should find little impact on the processing time and only an average of 2 x image size on disk space.

Answer (score 0):

Or in another way you can use [VideoCapture()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture) class to open url image.

See the  C++ code below,

```
VideoCapture cap;

if(!cap.open("http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/_downloads/opencv-logo.png")){
cout<<"Cannot open image"<<endl;
return -1;
}
Mat src;
cap>>src;
imshow("src",src);
waitKey();
```